# How do I prevent users from modifying resources they do not own?

Tags: web-application, webserver

I am writing a server where I have an entity `StoreOwner` that "owns" or has a `@OneToMany` relationship to a `Store` entity (one store owner has 1 to N stores). Each `Store` has `Offer` and `Item`, each also have a `@OneToMany` relationship with the store (one store has 1 to N offers and 1 to N items).

I am already using GWT Xsrf protection **and** a session ID that gets associated with the logged in user after each log-in (cookie).

There's one thing missing IMHO: what if a logged in user sends a *delete* request to the server with IDs of items that he does not own of a store he does not own either? At the moment, I am doing this in my `StoreService`:

```
// StoreService.java

@Transactional
public ItemDTO deleteItem(String sessionId, Long storeId, ItemDTO itemDto) {

    // sessionId is the cookie I have placed in my database
    // This way I want to ensure that I am only accessing a store
    // that is associated with the logged in store owner (the user basically)
    Store store = this.storeOwnerRepository.getStore(sessionId, storeId);

    Item item = ConvertDTO.convertItem(store, itemDto);

    // Check if the store ID that I got using the cookie is the
    // same ID as the store ID from the item that should be deleted
    if(item .getStore().getId() == store.getId()) {
        item = this.storeOwnerRepository.deleteItem(item);
    } else {
        // If this didn't work we have a potentially hostile user:
        throw new RuntimeException("Is somebody trying to delete items of a store he doesn't own?");
    }

    itemDto = ConvertEntity.convertItem(item);
    return itemDto;
}
```

It is the first time that I am trying to write a bigger server application and I want to prevent users from doing such things.

My question is twofold: [1] does what I am doing would really prevent a logged in user from smuggling the IDs of another store he does not own to my server? In addition, [2] can I simplify this a little bit?

My problem is that as the application grows one might - every now and then - forget this check

```
if(item .getStore().getId() == store.getId()) { /* .. */ }
```

Of course, I could move that into my `StoreOwnerRepository`, but do I have better options?

Comment: [Declarative security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401263/what-is-declarative-security-in-general) is generally simpler and less error prone than the programmatic security that you are currently using. Spring security, mentioned in @NeilMcGuigan's answer, supports declarative security and will generally be less error prone.

Comment: @NeilSmithline Thanks for the hint! Spring Security it is! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is called Access Control.

You need to check that a user has access to a record before performing an operation on it.

The simplest method would be to use a different database or schema per tenant. Or...

As you use Java, you could use Spring Security. It now [integrates](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#data) with Spring Data JPA, allowing you to pass in the userid/username into your SQL queries easily.

Or use Row Security right in the database. Oracle if you have $10M to spare, or this will be available for PostgreSQL in October. You can [mimic it with updateable security_barrier CHECK OPTION views](http://blog.databasepatterns.com/2014/12/postgresql-row-level-security-rls-vpd.html) as of PG 9.4. For this you'd have to have the [web server tell the db server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998597/switch-role-after-connecting-to-database/19602050#19602050) the name of the current user.

You probably want to add an `owner_id` column to your "child" tables. Use an `on update cascade` foreign key to the parent table.

Comment: Hi! [Maybe you can help me a little out here again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32657381/should-i-use-spring-secutiry-hibernate-or-hibernate-filters-for-access-control). I am not sure if I'm getting it how to do what I needed in my question with Spring Security. I understand how Spring Security can help me to determine if a user has the *role* to e.g. delete or modify something but I don't understand how to use it to determine that the resource belongs in fact to *another* user.